# Reverse for 'detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']

Tags: python, django, templates, web

hi everyone i got this error when i post a comment although the comment is posting but it give me this error and do not go to any redirect URL
my views.py file is:

```html
class CommentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'add-comment.html'
    # fields = '__all__'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.product = Product.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return super().form_valid(form)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('products:detail')
```

my urls.py is:

```html
urlpatterns = [
    path('' , ProductListView.as_view(), name= "list"),
    path('new/' , ProductCreateView.as_view() , name="product-create"),
    path('<slug:slug>/update/' , ProductUpdateView.as_view() , name="product-update"),
    path('<slug:slug>/delete/' , ProductDeleteView.as_view() , name="product-delete"),
    
    path('<slug:slug>/comment' , CommentCreateView.as_view() , name="add-comment"),
    path('<slug:slug>' , ProductDetailSlugView.as_view() , name="detail"),


]
```

my models.py file is:

```html
class Comment(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product , related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body=models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse("products:detail", kwargs={"slug" : self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s'%(self.product.title, self.name)
```

and my add-comment.html is:

```html
{% extends "base.html"%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags%}
{% block content %}
  <h2 class="text-center">comment here...</h2>
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
 <form method="POST">

   {% csrf_token %}
     <fieldset class="form-group">
    {{form|crispy}}
     </fieldset>
   
     <button class="btn btn-secondary" >Add comment</button>
 </form>
```

and when i click on add comment it is adding comment but do not redirect to that page. the error is:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anMro.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to redirect to `success_url = reverse_lazy('products:detail')` but without any argument (e.g. a slug).

You should rather use:

```py
class CommentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'add-comment.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.product = Product.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', kwargs={'slug' : self.object.slug})
```

Here, you get the url through `get_success_url` and you can pass in the slug of the created instance.

Comment: now it gave me an error that" comment object has no attribute slug"

Comment: although it is posting the comment